# JVM Crash outside of the JVM in native code

Tags: java, jvm

After importing my project to my school computer using IntelliJ's Version Control, I went to test my project, but was met with this error upon running:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fff45fcecfd, pid=4344, tid=0x0000000000002a8c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [lwjgl_opengl.dll+0xecfd]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I checked out the log file, and it looks like this:

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000174df000):  JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10892, stack(0x0000000018750000,0x0000000018850000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000000009d8

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000055b41d50, RBX=0x000000001710c080, RCX=0x0000000000000001, RDX=0x0000000019a6812c
RSP=0x000000001884ee68, RBP=0x000000001884eee8, RSI=0x0000000019a6812c, RDI=0x000000000299835d
R8 =0x0000000000000001, R9 =0x0000000019a6812c, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x00000000555cbc50
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000001710c080, R14=0x000000001884ef18, R15=0x00000000174df000
RIP=0x00007fff45fcecfd, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001884ee68)
0x000000001884ee68:   00000000029a7f74 000000000299835d
0x000000001884ee78:   00000000029a7ceb 00000000174df000
0x000000001884ee88:   000000001710c080 0000000019a6812c
0x000000001884ee98:   00000000174df000 00000000029a7ca2
0x000000001884eea8:   000000001884eea8 000000001710c080
0x000000001884eeb8:   000000001884ef18 00000000170d6d90
0x000000001884eec8:   0000000000000000 000000001710c080
0x000000001884eed8:   0000000000000000 000000001884ef08
0x000000001884eee8:   000000001884ef60 000000000299835d
0x000000001884eef8:   00000000d7dad188 00000000029a19d8
0x000000001884ef08:   0000000019a6812c 00000000d5da3138
0x000000001884ef18:   0000000000000001 000000001884ef20
0x000000001884ef28:   000000001710c1d4 000000001884ef90
0x000000001884ef38:   00000000170d6d90 0000000000000000
0x000000001884ef48:   000000001710c240 000000001884ef08
0x000000001884ef58:   000000001884ef90 000000001884efd8 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fff45fcecfd)
0x00007fff45fcecdd:   49 ff a2 00 0f 00 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
0x00007fff45fceced:   cc cc cc 48 8b 01 49 8b d1 41 8b c8 4c 8b 50 18
0x00007fff45fcecfd:   49 ff a2 d8 09 00 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
0x00007fff45fced0d:   cc cc cc 48 8b 01 49 8b d1 41 8b c8 4c 8b 50 18 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000055b41d50 is an unknown value
RBX={method} {0x000000001710c088} 'nglDeleteTextures' '(IJ)V' in 'org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11'
RCX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000019a6812c is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001884ee68 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000174df000
RBP=0x000000001884eee8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000174df000
RSI=0x0000000019a6812c is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000000299835d is at code_begin+2301 in an Interpreter codelet
invoke return entry points  [0x0000000002997a60, 0x0000000002998440]  2528 bytes
R8 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000019a6812c is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000555cbc50 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x000000001710c088} 'nglDeleteTextures' '(IJ)V' in 'org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11'
R14=0x000000001884ef18 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000174df000
R15=0x00000000174df000 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000018750000,0x0000000018850000],  sp=0x000000001884ee68,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [lwjgl_opengl.dll+0xecfd]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.nglDeleteTextures(IJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDeleteTextures(I)V+20
j  nitrodragon.render.Texture.finalize()V+4
j  java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+1
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Lsun/misc/JavaLangAccess;)V+46
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Ljava/lang/ref/Finalizer;Lsun/misc/JavaLangAccess;)V+2
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run()V+45
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000199e5000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6692, stack(0x000000001e6d0000,0x000000001e7d0000)]
  0x0000000018d4e000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7596, stack(0x0000000019340000,0x0000000019440000)]
  0x0000000018d20800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8948, stack(0x0000000019240000,0x0000000019340000)]
  0x0000000018cc7800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10968, stack(0x0000000019140000,0x0000000019240000)]
  0x0000000018cc3800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9996, stack(0x0000000019040000,0x0000000019140000)]
  0x0000000018c74800 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10044, stack(0x0000000018f40000,0x0000000019040000)]
  0x00000000174ef800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9520, stack(0x0000000018a40000,0x0000000018b40000)]
  0x00000000028be800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4548, stack(0x0000000018940000,0x0000000018a40000)]
=>0x00000000174df000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10892, stack(0x0000000018750000,0x0000000018850000)]
  0x00000000028b5000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11216, stack(0x0000000018650000,0x0000000018750000)]
  0x00000000027c4000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=10556, stack(0x0000000002490000,0x0000000002590000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000174b7800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000018550000,0x0000000018650000] [id=6940]
  0x0000000018e3f800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000019440000,0x0000000019540000] [id=11940]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 6424K [0x00000000d5d00000, 0x00000000da800000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 3% used [0x00000000d5d00000,0x00000000d5e49658,0x00000000d7d80000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d827cd58,0x00000000d8280000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000da300000,0x00000000da300000,0x00000000da800000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 337K [0x0000000081600000, 0x0000000086b80000, 0x00000000d5d00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081600000,0x00000000816545b0,0x0000000086b80000)
 Metaspace       used 10730K, capacity 10899K, committed 11136K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 974K, capacity 1069K, committed 1152K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011d50000,0x0000000012150000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011945000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000055bbd850
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012800000, 0x00000000147a8000)
 End Bits:   [0x00000000147a8000, 0x0000000016750000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000b90000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=3392Kb max_used=3405Kb free=242367Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002990000, 0x0000000002cf0000, 0x0000000011990000]
 total_blobs=1738 nmethods=881 adapters=768
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 2.195 Thread 0x0000000018cc7800  864       4       org.joml.Matrix4f::mul (7 bytes)
Event: 2.195 Thread 0x0000000018cc3800 nmethod 869 0x0000000002cd8d50 code [0x0000000002cd8ee0, 0x0000000002cd9528]
Event: 2.195 Thread 0x0000000018cc3800  865       4       nitrodragon.render.Shader::setUniform (20 bytes)
Event: 2.196 Thread 0x0000000018d20800  877       3       java.nio.Bits::tryReserveMemory (51 bytes)
Event: 2.196 Thread 0x0000000018d20800 nmethod 877 0x0000000002cdb290 code [0x0000000002cdb420, 0x0000000002cdba50]
Event: 2.197 Thread 0x0000000018cc7800 nmethod 864 0x0000000002cdd490 code [0x0000000002cdd5e0, 0x0000000002cdd768]
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x0000000018cc7800  878   !   4       java.lang.ref.Reference::tryHandlePending (115 bytes)
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x0000000018d20800  879   !   3       java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream::close (67 bytes)
Event: 2.199 Thread 0x0000000018d20800 nmethod 879 0x0000000002cda4d0 code [0x0000000002cda6a0, 0x0000000002cdae98]
Event: 2.199 Thread 0x0000000018d20800  880       3       sun.misc.VM::addFinalRefCount (24 bytes)

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 2.130 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 33280K [0x00000000d5d00000, 0x00000000d8780000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 100% used [0x00000000d5d00000,0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d7d80000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8280000,0x00000000d8280000,0x00000000d8780000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d8280000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 0K [0x0000000081600000, 0x0000000086b80000, 0x00000000d5d00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081600000,0x0000000081600000,0x0000000086b80000)
 Metaspace       used 10724K, capacity 10899K, committed 11136K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 974K, capacity 1069K, committed 1152K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2.182 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 5107K [0x00000000d5d00000, 0x00000000da800000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 0% used [0x00000000d5d00000,0x00000000d5d00000,0x00000000d7d80000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d827cd58,0x00000000d8280000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000da300000,0x00000000da300000,0x00000000da800000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 337K [0x0000000081600000, 0x0000000086b80000, 0x00000000d5d00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081600000,0x00000000816545b0,0x0000000086b80000)
 Metaspace       used 10724K, capacity 10899K, committed 11136K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 974K, capacity 1069K, committed 1152K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 2.183 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002cce664 method=java.nio.Bits.tryReserveMemory(JI)Z @ 29
Event: 2.183 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002cca9a0 method=java.nio.Bits.tryReserveMemory(JI)Z @ 29
Event: 2.184 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002cc38d0 method=java.nio.Bits.tryReserveMemory(JI)Z @ 29
Event: 2.192 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002cc0500 method=java.nio.Bits.tryReserveMemory(JI)Z @ 29
Event: 2.192 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002cb38a0 method=java.nio.Bits.tryReserveMemory(JI)Z @ 29
Event: 2.197 Thread 0x00000000028b5000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002cd94a8 method=java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Z)Z @ 17
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x00000000028b5000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002cd94a8 method=java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Z)Z @ 17
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x00000000028b5000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002cd94a8 method=java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Z)Z @ 17
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x00000000028b5000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002cd94a8 method=java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Z)Z @ 17
Event: 2.199 Thread 0x00000000174df000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002cb06ec method=java.lang.ThreadLocal.get()Ljava/lang/Object; @ 11

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.460 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000d62ad5f0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u144\9417\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.463 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000d62bb498) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u144\9417\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.558 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d64c3bb8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u144\9417\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.558 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d64c3dc8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u144\9417\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.559 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d64c7ec0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u144\9417\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.559 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d64c80d0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u144\9417\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.783 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x00000000d6770ae8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u144\9417\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 0.783 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x00000000d6772558) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u144\9417\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 1.258 Thread 0x00000000027c4000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000d71208d0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u144\9417\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 2.199 Thread 0x00000000174df000 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000002cb061c to 0x0000000002cb06d5

Events (10 events):
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x00000000028b5000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000029d582a sp=0x000000001874f168 mode 2
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x00000000028b5000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffffde fr.pc=0x0000000002cd94a8
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x00000000028b5000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000002cd94a8 sp=0x000000001874f1c0
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x00000000028b5000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000029d582a sp=0x000000001874f168 mode 2
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x00000000028b5000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffffde fr.pc=0x0000000002cd94a8
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x00000000028b5000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000002cd94a8 sp=0x000000001874f1c0
Event: 2.198 Thread 0x00000000028b5000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000029d582a sp=0x000000001874f168 mode 2
Event: 2.199 Thread 0x00000000174df000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x0000000002cb06ec
Event: 2.199 Thread 0x00000000174df000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000002cb06ec sp=0x000000001884ee80
Event: 2.199 Thread 0x00000000174df000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000029d582a sp=0x000000001884ee20 mode 2


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6356c0000 - 0x00007ff6356f7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe
0x00007fff5cdb0000 - 0x00007fff5cf8b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007fff5a940000 - 0x00007fff5a9ee000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007fff596c0000 - 0x00007fff59909000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007fff5a890000 - 0x00007fff5a931000     C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007fff5ccf0000 - 0x00007fff5cd8d000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007fff5afa0000 - 0x00007fff5aff9000     C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007fff5a460000 - 0x00007fff5a585000     C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007fff5b300000 - 0x00007fff5b44a000     C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007fff593d0000 - 0x00007fff593ee000     C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007fff5a7d0000 - 0x00007fff5a7f7000     C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007fff59980000 - 0x00007fff59b08000     C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007fff592d0000 - 0x00007fff5936a000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007fff595c0000 - 0x00007fff596b6000     C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007fff4f480000 - 0x00007fff4f6e7000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.15063.483_none_26002d27e7c744a2\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007fff5b000000 - 0x00007fff5b2f9000     C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
0x00007fff59910000 - 0x00007fff5997a000     C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007fff5a740000 - 0x00007fff5a76d000     C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x0000000055c40000 - 0x0000000055d12000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x00000000553a0000 - 0x0000000055c3d000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007fff5a590000 - 0x00007fff5a598000     C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007fff4f790000 - 0x00007fff4f799000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007fff5b7a0000 - 0x00007fff5b80c000     C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007fff4ca60000 - 0x00007fff4ca6a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007fff57790000 - 0x00007fff577b3000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007fff57730000 - 0x00007fff5775b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007fff59b10000 - 0x00007fff59b59000     C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000055390000 - 0x000000005539f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000055360000 - 0x0000000055389000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000055330000 - 0x0000000055353000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x0000000055310000 - 0x0000000055326000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007fff5b8b0000 - 0x00007fff5cce7000     C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007fff5ae90000 - 0x00007fff5af3a000     C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007fff59b60000 - 0x00007fff5a252000     C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007fff5af40000 - 0x00007fff5af91000     C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007fff59290000 - 0x00007fff592a1000     C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007fff59240000 - 0x00007fff5928c000     C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007fff59220000 - 0x00007fff59235000     C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007fff49380000 - 0x00007fff4939a000     C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3\bin\breakgen64.dll
0x00000000552f0000 - 0x000000005530a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007fff58ad0000 - 0x00007fff58b2c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00000000552d0000 - 0x00000000552e1000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x00007fff47c20000 - 0x00007fff47c77000     C:\Users\reaganrussell\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjglreaganrussell\3.1.2-build-29\lwjgl.dll
0x00007fff48a70000 - 0x00007fff48aac000     C:\Users\REAGAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjglreaganrussell\3.1.2-build-29\jemalloc.dll
0x00007fff46960000 - 0x00007fff4699d000     C:\Users\REAGAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjglreaganrussell\3.1.2-build-29\glfw.dll
0x00007fff57980000 - 0x00007fff57a15000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007fff46020000 - 0x00007fff46062000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dinput8.dll
0x00007fff577f0000 - 0x00007fff577fe000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\xinput1_4.dll
0x00007fff57c30000 - 0x00007fff57c58000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00007fff576d0000 - 0x00007fff576fa000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
0x00007fff5b450000 - 0x00007fff5b5b6000     C:\Windows\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007fff5b5d0000 - 0x00007fff5b690000     C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007fff58000000 - 0x00007fff5800d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL
0x00007fff5a9f0000 - 0x00007fff5ae2b000     C:\Windows\System32\SETUPAPI.DLL
0x00007fff59370000 - 0x00007fff593c6000     C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.dll
0x00007fff592b0000 - 0x00007fff592c1000     C:\Windows\System32\MSASN1.dll
0x00007fff593f0000 - 0x00007fff595b9000     C:\Windows\System32\CRYPT32.dll
0x00007fff3f3f0000 - 0x00007fff3f511000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\opengl32.dll
0x00007fff3f380000 - 0x00007fff3f3ac000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
0x00007fff34430000 - 0x00007fff34c62000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ig7icd64.dll
0x00007fff53800000 - 0x00007fff53c64000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igdusc64.dll
0x00007fff576b0000 - 0x00007fff576c3000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x00007fff52950000 - 0x00007fff529d2000     C:\Windows\System32\TextInputFramework.dll
0x00007fff54ed0000 - 0x00007fff551a2000     C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll
0x00007fff57070000 - 0x00007fff57153000     C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll
0x00007fff58530000 - 0x00007fff58561000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
0x00007fff559f0000 - 0x00007fff55b29000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
0x00007fff55950000 - 0x00007fff55965000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\usermgrcli.dll
0x00007fff45fc0000 - 0x00007fff4601c000     C:\Users\reaganrussell\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjglreaganrussell\3.1.2-build-29\lwjgl_opengl.dll
0x0000000055130000 - 0x00000000552c8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x00007fff57630000 - 0x00007fff576ae000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
0x00007fff4b5d0000 - 0x00007fff4b779000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=./lib -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=52248:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: nitrodragon.game.Main
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\reaganrussell\Desktop\Thundering Tests\lwjgl3_stuff\bin;C:\Users\reaganrussell\Desktop\Thundering Tests\lwjgl3_stuff\lib\lwjgl-assimp-natives-windows.jar;C:\Users\reaganrussell\Desktop\Thundering Tests\lwjgl3_stuff\lib\lwjgl-assimp.jar;C:\Users\reaganrussell\Desktop\Thundering Tests\lwjgl3_stuff\lib\lwjgl-glfw-natives-windows.jar;C:\Users\reaganrussell\Desktop\Thundering Tests\lwjgl3_stuff\lib\lwjgl-glfw.jar;C:\Users\reaganrussell\Desktop\Thundering Tests\lwjgl3_stuff\lib\lwjgl-openal-natives-windows.jar;C:\Users\reaganrussell\Desktop\Thundering Tests\lwjgl3_stuff\lib\lwjgl-openal.jar;C:\Users\reaganrussell\Desktop\Thundering Tests\
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\reaganrussell\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\[redacted]\Desktop\Git\cmd
USERNAME=[redacted]
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 15063 (10.0.15063.296)

CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 8293044k(3366196k free), swap 9603764k(3499084k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_144-b01), built on Jul 21 2017 21:57:33 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Thu Sep 28 10:39:39 2017
elapsed time: 2 seconds (0d 0h 0m 2s)
```

So, I reinstalled my libraries (I'm using LWJGL 3.1.3 and JOML 1.9.4) and tried to set up a Maven dependency instead, but neither solutions worked. What else should I do? My code runs well at home, so it's highly likely it's not an issue with that.

Comment: Can you edit your question and give the versions of lwjgl and joml. Along with that, a small bit of runnable code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @rjdkolb The code's rather large and requires most, if not all of it to run. Should I link my Github repo?

Comment: Rather try make a small program to reproduce the issue. It will help you as well. jwjgl is probably crashing on your specific OS at school which is the difference. Please indicate the exact versions of OS it works on and which one not. e.g. Windows 10 64 bit, or Windows 7 32 bit

Comment: Check if you are running the same versions of Java. And try to check if the native library `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjglreaganrussell\3.1.2-build-29\lwjgl_opengl.dll` fits the target system.

Comment: @rjdkolb Win10 64-bit at school, Win7 64-bit at home.

Comment: @blafasel Okay, so the error's back on both platforms. I've messed with the DLL's and the error goes away for about 2 runs, then comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the stacktrace:

```
j  nitrodragon.render.Texture.finalize()V+4
j  java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+1
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Lsun/misc/JavaLangAccess;)V+46
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Ljava/lang/ref/Finalizer;Lsun/misc/JavaLangA ccess;)V+2
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run()V+45
```

you are calling OpenGL functions inside of a finalize() method (inherited from Object.finalize()). You cannot do this, since the finalize() method is called by a special Finalizer thread at some point during Garbage Collection, in which obviously your OpenGL context is not current.

That is why LWJGL crashes.

Answer (score -1):

1.8.0_231 resolved the error for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).